# How do I set default index sort_order that ignore case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Current I am following activeadmin guide on [their site](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html#index-default-sort-order):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Brand do
  config.sort_order = 'brand_name_asc'
end
```

But turn out this method sorts the selected column (brand_name) alphabetically case sensitive.

How can I make a default sort_order that ignore case?

Comment: Isn't this dependent on the db and the collation used on the column. A workaround would be to maybe use `lower(brand_name_asc)`. That does however have some performance issues with large sets, because it doesn't use indexes I believe.

Comment: config.sort_order = lower(brand_name_asc) ? This collection is very small, so performance is not an issue, we only have 8 brands or so

Comment: Yeah, just try that. Depending on if you're using mysql or postgres there are other solutions for this also.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I'm using postgresql. What exactly is the other solution?

Comment: Nice, thank you so much. Do you want to make an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using postgres you can do it like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Brand do
  config.sort_order = 'lower(brand_name_asc)'
end
```

Note: This does have some performance issues with large sets, because it probably doesn't use indexes, but the op has only 8 items so it doesn't matter.